# Testing UI / set focus on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I have a problem with testing the value of a TextBox. First of all i show you the code of the testcase:

```
[TestCase]
public void trage_kilogramm_ein()
{
    var windowPeer = new FrameworkElementAutomationPeer(this.zieleTest);
    var liste = windowPeer.GetChildren();
    var boxPeer = (TextBoxAutomationPeer)liste[34];
    boxPeer.VerifyAccess();
    var buttonPeer = (ButtonAutomationPeer)liste[9];
    var button = (Button)buttonPeer.Owner;
    var box = (TextBox)boxPeer.Owner;
    box.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    box.VerifyAccess();
    box.Focus();
    testWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action    (boxPeer.SetFocus));
    var args = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, button);
    button.RaiseEvent(args);
    Assert.AreEqual("8", ((IValueProvider)boxPeer).Value);
}
```

I have a window with 10 TextBoxes where you can put values in. I also have 10 Buttons for the numbers from 0 to 9 which just send key events for a specific number. In the code i simulate the click event for the number/button "8". My problem is that i can`t set the focus onto the TextBox. My test always fails because the "TextBox.Text" is still "String.Empty" and does not get the value "8".

Thanks.

// EDIT:
Okay, now i get the focus. It seemed that I needed to set the focus on the parent.
I wrote two Methods to see if I get the KeyboardFocus.

```
private void Gewicht_obere_OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got Focus");
}

private void Gewicht_obere_OnLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Focus Lost");
}
```

The problem is now i get the focus but i lost it immediately.

Comment: BeginInvoke on the dispatcher is an async call. So it might be that you execute the assert before the focus is set. Do you get the same result if you just use Dispatcher.Invoke?

Comment: It`s still the same result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the reference for the specific control(in that case TextBox).

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                control.Focus();
            });
```